# Confusion about distribution of errors in linear models

Tags: measurement-error

I can't get something settled in my mind regarding epsilon.

So let's say that the "real" model in the population looks like that: **y = a + bX + ε**.
just a simple linear regression.

one of the assumptions of OLS is that ε ~N(0,σ).

and another assumption of OLS is that every single ε has the same probability density function (PDF).

so we actually talking about two separate types of distributions:
one suggesting that each ε has its own (but identical to all others) PDF,
and the other regards that all ε together suppose to be normally distributed with expectation of zero.

Can someone explain how both of those types of distributions are connected?

Comment: As you said, the assumption is that each $\epsilon$ is normally distributed with mean 0 and variance $\sigma$ and they are uncorrelated with each other. Due to a property of the normal distribution, those assumptions mean that their joint distribution is a multivariate normal with a mean vector of zeros and a diagonal variance-covariance matrix with each term on the diagonal equal to $\sigma$ and the off-diagonal terms equal to zero.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/959458/is-the-joint-distribution-of-two-independent-normally-distributed-random-variab) question

Comment: @jmarkov That looks like an answer to me!

Comment: Haha thanks! I would like to write it as an answer with matrices' details, but my LaTex formula writing skills are poor so I gave up. I'll add it as an answer for now and update with the math later if I can. Should I delete the comment if I include it as an answer?

Comment: thank you very much @@jmarkov, it made it very clear for me even without the demonstration of the matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the assumption is that each $\epsilon$ is normally distributed with mean 0 and variance $\sigma$ and they are uncorrelated with each other. Due to a property of the normal distribution, those assumptions mean that their joint distribution is a multivariate normal with a mean vector of zeros and a diagonal variance-covariance matrix with each term on the diagonal equal to $\sigma$ and the off-diagonal terms equal to zero.

See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/959458/is-the-joint-distribution-of-two-independent-normally-distributed-random-variab) question for the joint distribution of two independent normal random variables.